# Jquery multiplication of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to multiply gc value to each count class and i want grand total in the input field of id total. gc value is taking from db

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function(){
             calculateSum();
             $(".count").keyup(calculateSum);
    });

  function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        console.log('called');
        $(".count").each(function() {
                console.log(this.value);
                if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                     sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }
        });
        $("#total").val(sum);         
   }
</script>
<input type='text' id='gc' name='gc' value="<?php echo $gc; ?>">
<input class='count'>
 <input class='count'>
 <input class='count'>
 <input class='count'>
<input id='total'>
```

Comment: `sum += parseFloat(this.value * $("#gc").val());`

Comment: What is the problem ? What error you getting

Comment: you should declare `sum` variable out of `calculateSum` function.

Comment: calculateSum();  in definition we dont have this for jquery selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like below to multiply values

```
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    console.log('called');
    $(".count").each(function() {
        console.log(this.value);
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
           sum += parseFloat(this.value * $("#gc").val());
        }
    });
    $("#total").val(sum);
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
sum += parseFloat(this.value) * $("#gc").val();
```

instead of this

```
sum += parseFloat(this.value);
```